# Consume Avro message from Kafka via Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, unmarshalling, apache-kafka

I have a Apache Camel route publishing an AVRO message onto a Apache Kafka topic. I only got this to work when setting the producer property 'serializerClass=kafka.serializer.StringEncoder'. Otherwise I get

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [B
>     at kafka.serializer.DefaultEncoder.toBytes(Encoder.scala:34)    at
>   kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$serialize$1.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:130)
>     at
>   kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$serialize$1.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:125)
>     at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
>     at
>   kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.serialize(DefaultEventHandler.scala:125)
>     at
>   kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:52)
>     at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)  at
>   kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)   at
>   org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaProducer.process(KafkaProducer.java:84)

On the other end I have a second Apache Camel route supposed to consume from the above topic which failes with

> java.io.IOException: Invalid long encoding    at
>   org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.innerLongDecode(BinaryDecoder.java:217)
>     at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readLong(BinaryDecoder.java:176)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readLong(ResolvingDecoder.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.dataformat.avro.AvroDataFormat.unmarshal(AvroDataFormat.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:67)

Here is the Apache Camel consumer code I use:

```
        <route id="cassandra.publisher">
            <from
                uri="{{kafka.base.uri}}&amp;topic=sensordata&amp;groupId=Cassandra_ConsumerGroup&amp;consumerId=CassandraConsumer_Instance_1&amp;clientId=adapter2" />      
            <unmarshal>
                <custom ref="avroSensorData" />
            </unmarshal>
```

Comment: Is it possible to post less code but still include the bit where the problem occurs? It would make it easier to identify the issue and help solve it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-Kafka-Component-td5749525.html#a5769561

describes that Apache Camel version 2.16.0/2.15.3 will support various datatype and not only String messages.

As promised this has been fixed with Apache Camel 2.15.3 and was fixed with CAMEL-8790 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8790).

Comment: Could you plese help me with how to add the route                            from("kafka:{{consumer.topic}}?brokers={{kafka.host}}:{{kafka.port}}"
                        + "&maxPollRecords={{consumer.maxPollRecords}}"
                        + "&consumersCount={{consumer.consumersCount}}"
                        + "&seekTo={{consumer.seekTo}}"
                        + "&groupId={{consumer.group}}"
                        +"&valueDeserializer="+KafkaAvroDeserializer.class
                       +"&keyDeserializer="+StringDeserializer.class
                        ).routeId("FromKafka")

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem you have to provide the keyDeserializer and valueDeserializer for camel kafka consumer as follows:

&keyDeserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer  &valueDeserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer